# Setting initial value for select2 with ajax data source

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I use select2 for specifying recipients for the website's inner messaging system. There are users and they can send messages to each other. They can search other users by the user name.

I use the following config:

```
this.$select2.select2({
  multiple: true,
  ajax: {
    url: "/userSearch",
    dataType: "json",
  },
  templateResult: function(data) {
    var user = new SomeComplexUserModel(data);
    var $div = $(<div></div>");
    $div.append("<img src='"+user.image.readPaths().crop+"'>");
    $div.append("<span>"+user.fullName()+"</span>");
    return $div;
  },
  templateSelection: ..the same as templateResult..
```

Now I want to set initial value for this. How to do that? I have the list of ids of the users that have to be selected on page load. I make the separate request to `/userSearch` and receive the data. Then I'm trying to push this data to the select2 somehow.

I can't create native `var opt = new Option(text,value); select.append(opt)` because this case templateSelection gets only id and text from the option, it can't construct the user model based on this data only. It does not show users with avatars.

I tried to trigger `select2:select` event with `{originalEvent:null,data:$.extend(ajaxResult,{selected:true,disabled:false,element:null},_type:"select")}`, but it seems it does not work this direction. It emits events but is not subscribed for them.

I also tried to set `this.$select2.val(ajaxData); this.$select2.trigger('change')`, after select2 initialization, but it does not work either.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having a similar challenge